# Synchronize data between .dbf files and Sql Server 2005

Tags: database

I have a legacy appplication written in delphi. Database is stored in multiple .dbf files . I have to expose some pages in asp.net using SQL server 2005. Now i want to sync both of these databases.

How should i proceed.Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Both applications should to have precise enough date field (timestamp in SQL, I don't recall specific in DBF). Everytime you update a field, you also update this field.

This way, to sync both databases you just need to compare record ID + date field to find records which needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of interest: http://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro

You may need to take account of records that have been marked for deletion but not packed.